# print single value form an array object in java

Tags: java

i am trying to print one value of an array object. Here i want to print "Price is £2000" but the 2000 is in the object. How do i get the 2000 from the object to be printed?

```
cars[7] = new Car(2000, 4, 4);
    System.out.println("Price is £"+    );
```

thank you all for your help

Comment: Is there a `getPrice()` method?  Call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a method that returns the integer.

Example:

```
class Car {

    int price;

    public Car (int price , int i , int h) {

        this.price = price;

    }

    public int getPrice() {

        return price;

    }

}
```

In your main class:

```
System.out.println("Price is £"+ cars[7].getPrice());
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Car class, have a `public int getPrice()` method that returns the price variable for the car.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look up OO programming.

how did you define class Car?

I will define in such way.

```
Class Car {
    private int firstValue;
    private int secValue;
    private int thirdValue;



    public int getfirstValue(){
        return this.firstValue;
    }
    ....

}
```

so, in this way, you can:

```
cars[7] = new Car(2000, 4, 4);
System.out.println("Price is £"+ cars[7].getfirstValue());
```

Comment: This answer has quite a few syntax errors. It's `class` not `Class`, and you are forgetting `public void getfirstvalue()`. Java would assume getfirstvalue is a constructor.

Comment: @GalenNare Thanks for point out. "constructor of object" means I ask the author to define constructor, it does not mean getfirstValue() is the constructor, but anyway, I did forget to add public int in front of the getfirstValue() as a return type int.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Price is £"+cars[7].getPrice());
```

For this, you should write the getter for price first as follows:

```
public int getPrice(){
    return price;
}
```

Comment: Where is this getPrice() method?

Answer (score 0):

Car is not an array.  Car is an Object type.  Car should have an access method to get the value.  Also, it could override Object.toString() so that it returns the "price" but that seems to be a poor toString implementation choice.